# how to use json_normalize but flip the axis

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Hey guys I've been working on converting some json text I'm receiving from an API and I noticed some people using json_normalize, but in my case it doesn't solve the full issue and I was wondering if someone could help.
import pandas as pd

```
my_json = [
    {
        "total": "null",
        "items": [
            {
                "key": "time",
                "label": "Time",
                "value": "2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00"
            },
            {
                "key": "agentNotes",
                "label": "Agent Notes",
                "value": "null"
            },
            {
                "key": "blindTransferToAgent",
                "label": "Blind Transfer To Agent",
                "value": "0"
            }]},
  {"total": "null",
        "items": [
            {
                "key": "time",
                "label": "Time",
                "value": "2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00"
            },
            {
                "key": "agentNotes",
                "label": "Agent Notes",
                "value": "null"
            },
            {
                "key": "blindTransferToAgent",
                "label": "Blind Transfer To Agent",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]}]
```

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_json, ["items"])
print(df)
```

This gives me a result like this

> ```
>                key  ...                          value
> 0                  time  ...  2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00
> 1            agentNotes  ...                           null
> 2  blindTransferToAgent  ...                              0
> ```

> ```
> [3 rows x 3 columns]
> ```

But I'm trying to create my keys as columns and the values as the values so the end result look like this.

> time agentNotes blindTransfertoAgent

> 2022-12-13T23:590:59.939-07:00 null 0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any shortcuts for this problem and maybe someone could enlighten us.
However the solution isn't that long, so I thought to post it anyways.

Your "JSON" isn't really a JSON if I am reading correctly from your question, it is a list that contains a dictionary with two keys, `total` and `items`. The value of `items` is a list of dictionaries, so we can iterate through the values and take the `key`-`value` elements from each one:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

dict_to_df = defaultdict(list)
dictionaries = [inner_dicts for items_dict in my_json for inner_dicts in items_dict['items']]

for dictionary in dictionaries:
    dict_to_df[dictionary['key']].append(dictionary['value'])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_to_df, orient='index').T
print(df)
```

Which outputs:

```
                            time agentNotes blindTransferToAgent
0  2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00       null                    0
```

---

###### Explanations:

- Initialize an empty defaultdict (with default value of a list) which we will read to a pandas dataframe.
- Insert the values per `key` in the "JSON" we have
- Read the dictionary into a pandas `DataFrame` - orienting the indices and transposing, if these values don't have the same length. (such as having one more `blindTransferToAgent` with value `1`) to get around if the JSON looks like:

```json
        {
            "key": "time",
            "label": "Time",
            "value": "2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00"
        },
        {
            "key": "agentNotes",
            "label": "Agent Notes",
            "value": "null"
        },
        {
            "key": "blindTransferToAgent",
            "label": "Blind Transfer To Agent",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "key": "blindTransferToAgent",
            "label": "Blind Transfer To Agent",
            "value": "4"
        }
```

Which will output:

```
                            time agentNotes blindTransferToAgent
0  2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00       null                    0
1                           None       None                    4
```

Comment: Thanks no_hex, I do believe the answer here is more correct. Yeah I guess I do have a list that is outputted so yeah not really true "JSON". I believe this will do the job! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just noticed a big misstep in my question. So each row in the data will have this format, so the list contains many total:null, items:[]...would I just loop over the list itself and do the processing you have mentioned ?

Comment: @Alex Hi, could you update the `items` list to your new example? I think it will work anyways because we loop over it.

Comment: yeah I will update the initial question.

Comment: just added another value in the list.

Comment: got it ```for i in range(0,len(data)):
  for dictionaries in data[i]['items']:
    dict_to_df[dictionaries['key']].append(dictionaries['value'])```

Comment: @Alex Nice! you could also normalize the input beforehand (updated my answer)

Comment: would yours be more performant since it's not an embedded loop like mine ?

Comment: @Alex In case of performance - I wouldn't care about it too much we are using Python anyways :) jokes aside - don't think there will be any difference between them, only cosmetically (whether you like two nested loops or one list comprehension with two for-loops)

Comment: thanks for your help yet again :D have a great one!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_json, ["items"])
```

into this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_json, ["items"]).T
```

The `T` attribute in a Pandas DataFrame object stores a transposition of the index and columns, which is what you're looking for.

Output:

```
                                   0            1                        2
key                             time   agentNotes     blindTransferToAgent
label                           Time  Agent Notes  Blind Transfer To Agent
value  2022-12-13T23:59:59.939-07:00         null                        0
```

Comment: wow all I needed was .T after my parentheses :D and then I would just drop the first row? it seems like the columns are 0, 1, 2 how would I make the labels the columns?